# remove stop words without stemming in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, stop-words

I want to remove the stop words from my data but I do not want to stem the words since the exact words matters to me. 
I used this query.

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english',colName)from tblName order by lower asc;
```

Is there any way that I can remove stopWords without stemming the words?

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create your own text search dictionary and configuration:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY simple_english
   (TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple, STOPWORDS = english);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english
   (copy = english);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english
   ALTER MAPPING FOR asciihword, asciiword, hword, hword_asciipart, hword_part, word
   WITH simple_english;
```

It works like this:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('simple_english', 'many an ox eats the houses');
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│             to_tsvector             │
├─────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 'eats':4 'houses':5 'many':1 'ox':3 │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

You can set the parameter `default_text_search_config` to `simple_english` to make it your default text search configuration.

Comment: I have done it, and then I made a query like this `update tblName set cilName= to_tsvector('simple_english',colName);` and then returns this error `value too long for type character varying(254)`!

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to store a `tsvector` in a `varchar` column. Particularly if you define it so short that it cannot hold the value. What are you trying to do?

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I have a column of tags, they can be some characters or even sentences. the tags can be the same, but these makes them look different. I want to remove the stop words and all the characters and find the distinctive tags.

Comment: should I change it to text? is it possible to change it now without losing any information?

Comment: Then you probably want to filter out the `:3` and similar. And you should define the column large enough to contain all words. Why not use type `text`?

Comment: Changing to `text` won't lose any information since `varchar` and `text` are the same thing anyway, the only difference being the length limit.