# Results from TO_TSVECTOR

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm using `TO_TSVECTOR` to generate a word cloud based on long-format user entries. It generally works well, returning the number of instances of a word. I'm however noticing some strange results. I suspect it's likely that I don't understand how lexemes work/are returned from `TO_TSVECTOR`. Here's my sample set:

```
"this is just another response"
"and yet again I am typing this because I think it will work"
"why is someone so loud moaning in this song?"
"oh hi mark"
"oh hi mark"
"the time has come, to make this thing work"
"white light, song lyrics are fun to play with"
"this is a test another test why wont you work?"
"what a morbid response"
```

I'm getting the results the way I'd typically expect however the words `another` and `response` are being returned as `anoth` and `respons`. So basically it's truncating the result?

If I use `TO_TSVECTOR` with the `simple` setting I get the results I want, however extra words like `the` and `it` aren't being filtered out (which is what I'd like).

As mentioned, suspect I'm misunderstanding how the lexemes are returned.

Comment: just `CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONAR` as https://stackoverflow.com/a/42063785/5315974

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove stop words without stemming in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052173/remove-stop-words-without-stemming-in-postgresql)